# DataFrame.to_records gives an error when type(index) is DatetimeIndex

Tags: pandas

`DataFrame.to_records` gives an error when type(index) is DatetimeIndex.

python version is 2.7.3, pandas is 0.8.1.

The following is an simple example code that make the error in IPython shell.

How can I get the right answer, an array of records from to_records method.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59)  
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.12.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.  
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.  
%quickref -> Quick reference.  
help      -> Python's own help system.  
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.  

In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.system('pip search pandas')
pandas                    - Powerful data structures for data analysis, time
                            series,and statistics
  INSTALLED: 0.8.1 (latest)
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: from pandas import *

In [4]: from numpy.random import randn

In [5]: data = randn(5,3)

In [6]: index = date_range('2012-08-01', periods=5)

In [7]: columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [8]: df = DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

In [9]: df  
Out[9]: 
                   a         b         c  
2012-08-01  2.355928 -2.465061  0.240094  
2012-08-02 -0.952323  0.746623 -0.384021  
2012-08-03  1.460156  0.292560 -0.494793  
2012-08-04 -0.989584 -1.630384  1.373587  
2012-08-05  0.014760 -0.789603 -0.622780  

In [10]: df.to_records()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)  
/home/ideabong/<ipython-input-10-6d3142e97d2d> in <module>()  
----> 1 df.to_records()  

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in to_records(self, index)  
    889             names = list(map(str, self.columns))  
    890   
--> 891         return np.rec.fromarrays(arrays, names=names)  
    892   
    893     @classmethod  

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/records.pyc in fromarrays(arrayList, dtype, shape, formats, names, titles, aligned, byteorder)  
    546     # Determine shape from data-type.  

    547     if len(descr) != len(arrayList):  
--> 548         raise ValueError, "mismatch between the number of fields "\  
    549               "and the number of arrays"  
    550   

ValueError: mismatch between the number of fields and the number of arrays
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed bug:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1720

Please use GitHub for bug reports.